# Add element after every ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat but I would like to add an element after every 4th repeated element.

the repeated div:

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="product in productList" ng-init="addFullScreenProduct($index, this)">
```

and then in my controller:

```
$scope.addFullScreenProduct = function(index, event)
{
        var currentProduct = "<div id='" + (index/4) + "' class='currentProduct sixteen columns'></div>";
        var product = event.srcElement;
        currentProduct = $compile(currentProduct)($scope);
        product.after(currentProduct);
};
```

I cannot get the "currentProduct" element to be added after the "product" element.

My Desired output:

```
<div class="currentProduct">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="currentProduct">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="product">...</div>
<div class="currentProduct">...</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: why not just use filter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="product in productList" class="product">
    {{ product }}
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end ng-if="$index % 4 == 0" class="currentproduct sixteen columns"></div>
```

The `div.product` will be repeated, with `div.currentproduct` being present at every fourth iteration.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. However it is saying that product is undefined... Not exactly sure why. I have imported: src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js" for angular.

Comment: Turns out I was using an old version of angular, this worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters to show every 4th element.. like this:

```
<div class="product" ng-repeat="product in productList" ng-show="$index % 4 == 0"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is not only showing every 4th element (I may have worded it poorly). What I need is to add a div after every 4th repeated element.

I need it to output like this:


    `<div class="currentProduct">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="currentProduct">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="currentProduct">...</div>`